# execl() is not working/printing

Tags: c, exec

I'm trying to run an exec command from a child process with a user input and it is not printing/working.

Here is my code:

```
char input[100];
int pid;

printf("$ ");
fgets(input, 100, stdin);

while (strncmp(input, "exit", 4)){
    pid = fork();
    if(pid == 0){
        char str[105];
        strcpy(str, "/bin/");
        strcat(str, input);
        printf("%s", str);
        execl(str, input, NULL);
        exit(0);
    }
    else if(pid < 0){       /* error while doing fork */
        exit(1);
    }
    else{
        wait(0);
    }

    printf("$ ");
    fgets(input, 10, stdin);
}

exit(0);
```

Comment: Do you have any sort of error or debug information?

Comment: I'm new with c so no. It compiles fine but nothing prints out when I do ls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `str` as well as `input` contain a newline character. Remove it before calling `execl`.

Comment: Trimming all the trailing whitespaces will be better.

Comment: I don't know if trimming is a good idea since I need to use the same array again.